# pattern to add to array item from child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I have two components, a parent and child one, the
parent data attribute I've set up it like this...

```
data () {
    return {
      users: [],
    }
 }
```

the users array is populated by a button click,  i share this array with the child component. 
The child component is trying to add a user to this list which works(adding value to passed in props), but because the users array is declared under data the parent component refreshes and i lose my users... 
is there a pattern to keep the users array values and add to them via a child...

sorry if this is obvious but as i said i'm just starting...

edit : adding code (parent component)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <button v-on:click="display()">Display users</button>
      <button v-on:click="displaySingleUserInput = 
           !displaySingleUserInput">Add user</button>
      <div>
    </div>

    <ul v-if="errors && errors.length">
      <li v-for="error of errors">
        {{error.message}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <add-user v-on:submit_user="addUser" v-show="displaySingleUserInput"></add-user>
    <user-list v-bind:users="users"></user-list>             
</div>

</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import UserList from './components/UserList';
import AddUser from './components/AddUser';

export default {
  components: {
    'user-list': UserList,
    'add-user': AddUser
  },
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      users: [],
      errors: [],
      displaySingleUserInput: false
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    display: function(string) 
    {
      axios.get(`users.json`)
        .then(response => {
          // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
          this.users = response.data.users
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
    },
    addUser: function(id) {
      this.users.push({firstname: "john", lastName: 'jones'})
        },
  }
}
</script>
```

child component

```
<template>
    <div id="singleUserAdd">
      <form id=addUser aria-label="single user add">
        <button v-on:click="submit()">Submit</button>
        <button>Cancel</button>
      </form>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function() {
          this.$emit('submit_user', 1)
        }    
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a method called `addUser` in your child component :

```
   addUser(){
     this.$emit("addusr",this.newuser);
    }
```

In the parent one :

```
   <child-comp @addusr="addNewUser" />

    ...
   addNewUser(newuser){
        this.users.push(newuser);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like i was missing

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit"
```

to stop my page from refreshing